# Are rights 7110 equivalent to --S--S--s?

Tags: unix, chmod

Are rights `7110` equivalent to `--S--S--s`?

I mean the rights for Unix' `chmod` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes](http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/7110/).

[image]

Comment: +1 for the link to a useful site, but you could have made it clear in your answer, such as "Yes, as indicated by this site - <link>"

Comment: It'd actually be `--s--s--T` as formatted by ls. --S--S--s is nonsense (since the last should be t), and would be 7001 in any case.